# Is it possible to get multiple data with fetch?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to get multiple data with fetch? 
In my example I get 'inputDest' value (email) and 'a' value (name). So my goal here is to get 'inputDest' and 'a' value and send it to an email.

```
const inputDest = document.querySelector('input[name=dest]');
   const a=document.querySelector('input[name=a]');
    document.querySelector('button[name=send-mail]').addEventListener('click', function(){
        fetch('https://us-central1-nastava-3ae81.cloudfunctions.net/sendMail?dest='+inputDest.value+'sendMail?a='+a.value)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                console.log(text);
            });
    }, false);
```

If I leave code like that of course I get an error:
Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 553-5.1.3 The recipient address  is not a
553 5.1.3 valid RFC-5321 address. m189sm881135ioa.17 - gsmtp

So, inside my functions is basically this

```
exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
cors(req, res,  () => {

    const dest = req.query.dest;
    const a=req.query.a;

    const mailOptions = {
        from: '<something@gmail.com>',
        to: dest,
        subject: a, 
        html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">Pickle </p> ` 
    };

    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
        if(erro){
            return res.send(erro.toString());
        }
        return res.send('Sended');
    });
});    
});
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand what your question is asking, but it looks like you're not building the query string correctly.

Comment: My question is it possible to put multiple data inside fetch? If I put only one data like inputDest then it works fine.

Comment: Depends if the api supports it. You can put as much data as you want inside fetch, but what matters is how the API server consumes the data.

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  Your web client and function will need to agree on how to pass that data.

Comment: Edited, give it a look.

Comment: The title says "get", but the body of the question appears to talk about "sending" multiple pieces of data. Which is it?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question but from what I see, I can tell this looks wrong: `fetch('https://us-central1-nastava-3ae81.cloudfunctions.net/sendMail?dest='+inputDest.value+'sendMail?a='+a.value)` .... wouldn't it be `".../sendMail?dest=" + encodeURIComponent(inputDest.value) + "&a=" + encodeURIComponent(a.value)`?

Comment: If you're trying to send multiple, you likely want `sendMail?dest='+inputDest.value+'&a='+a.value`, as that's how URLs are constructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send multiple values to the server in a (in this instance) `GET` request by using the `?` and `&` symbols.

The `?` symbol indicates that the following string sequence are values that the server can read.
The `&` symbol is a seperation between values.
Every value has to be a *key-value* pair like `key=value`.

Consider the following `fetch` request.

```
fetch('https://example.com/user?first_name=foo&last_name=bar')
```

In this example we are sending `first_name` and `last_name` to the `https://example.com/user` URL. There the server is able to read these values.

In PHP it would be like the example below.

```
$first_name = $_GET['first_name']; // foo
$last_name = $_GET['last_name']; // bar
```

I hope this helps you out.